# How To Create a Custom Block in Custom Module?

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks

I have followed a tutorial to create the block. All codes are in here 
http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-create-block-44

but I cant seem to connect to the template file, no matter where i put it. i tried the base then tried the default and then tried the rwd. it still does not connect. i changed the default package through admin panel to rwd and it still wont work. any comment or suggestions will be highly helpful. I am stuck in it for days.

Comment: Could you add your config.xml, controller.php and layout.xml. It may be a issue with your (`<routeurfrontend_index_index>`) route

Comment: @beginner : Just to have a curiosity : why did you unmark tick from my answer ? and put tick on sukeshini's answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be missed some of the sections in your module. Double check and verify whether you have the done the followings.

> 1. Module activation file.

Create a file in `app/etc/modules` as `Pfay_Test.xml`. See below.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> 2. Put your layout and template files under the `current activated theme`
> 3. Clear the cache or disable while you developing the modules. Go to `System > Cache Management`

### I'll put all the content which should work. If you don't have any of the above issues please check you have all the files below

1.) Pfay/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <test>
                <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
        <layout>
           <updates>
                <test>
                     <file>test.xml</file>
                 </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

2.) Pfay/Test/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout ();
        $this->renderLayout ();
    }

    public function mamethodeAction()
    {
        echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}
```

3.) Pfay/Test/Block/Monblock.php

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        return 'informations about my block !!';
    }
}
```

4.) app/etc/modules/Pfay_Test.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

5.) app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/test.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
        </reference>
    </default>
    <test_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/monblock" name="afficher_monbloc" template="test/afficher.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </test_index_index>
</layout>
```

6.) app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/test/afficher.phtml

`<h1>Hello</h1>`

Comment: my default package is rwd, the xml is not connecting to the template. this is the path to the template. public_html/dev/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/test. am i doing anything wrong ? my layout is in public_html/dev/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout.

Comment: New layout and template files belong in base/default. Always and forever.

Comment: Go to ` System > Configuration > Design ` and verify your current theme. And ensure that you have some text in your template file and the front name is correct

Comment: i did, its in rwd. i have other modules created by someone else and they all work.

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Comment: the code is the same as the examples. somehow rkt code worked. thanks for the help. i do understand the basic developer guide of magento but somehow i always mess things up.

Answer (score 7):

So you just want to create your own custom block. Then follow these steps. I am going to call this module as `Rkt_CustomBlock`.

First of all, these are the files that are avilable in this extension

```
rootdir
|________ app
        |________ etc
        |           - Rkt_CustomBlock.xml
        |________ code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock
        |       |________ etc
        |       |           - config.xml
        |       |________ controllers
        |       |           - IndexController.php
        |       |           
        |       |________ Block
        |                   - Helloworld.php
        |               
        |________ design/frontend/rwd/default
                |________ layout
                |           - rkt_customblock.xml
                |________ template/rkt_customblock
                            - helloworld.phtml
```

First of you need to carefully construct this file structure. Now we can go into the codes.

### Module Activation File

File : `app\etc\modules/Rkt_CustomBlock.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_CustomBlock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Rkt_CustomBlock>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This file is used to activate our custom module. Here it does two things. First it makes our module enabled (`<active>true</active>`) and secondly defines where our module is going to reside. According to the definition, our module is going to reside in `local` codepool.

### Module Configuration File

file : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_CustomBlock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rkt_CustomBlock>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <rkt_customblock>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Rkt_CustomBlock</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </rkt_customblock>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <rkt_customblock>
                    <file>rkt_customblock.xml</file>
                </rkt_customblock>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <rkt_customblock>
                <class>Rkt_CustomBlock_Block</class>
            </rkt_customblock>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

This file is used to configure our module. `<modules>` node is used to define version of our module. Here our module version is `1.0.0` This section is not important for us. Since we only deal with blocks. So this part is not necessary in our case. But it is a good practice to add this section in our module.

`<frontend>` section is used to declare a unique `router` and a frontend `layout xml` file for our extension. Here we set router `<frontName>` as `helloworld`. This means any url which is going to follow `www.yourdomain.com/helloworld/...` format is going to use our module. We declared a layout xml file for our extension only to add layout updates of our own custom extension.

`<global>` section is used to declare our block section. The code inside this node two things here. First it set a unique identifier for extension's block. Here it is `rkt_customblock` (in general `namespace_modulename`). Beware.. it should be unique. Also it defines where exactly extension is going to hold block classes. According to the defintion, it will be at `Rkt_CustomBlock_Block`. Magento parse this value to the location `app\code\local/Rkt/CustomBlock/Block` to find our custom block classes.

### Controller of our Extension

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

First our controller extends from the class `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`. This is very important. Every frontend controller classes should extend from this core class.

Now as you can see our controller holds only one method `indexAction()` and it just loads the layout and then render those layout. Those two simple, humble lines of codes do a lot and I dont want to explain all those things here. You just want to know, those codes are responsible for constituting a magento page. Generally almost every controller action method hold these two line of codes.

### Define Custom Block

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/Block/Helloworld.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getText()
    {
        return "I am inside `" . get_class(). "` block and it is my first custom block ever !";
    }
}
```

`Helloworld` is our custom block. This block is going to show in frontend. You can see that our block extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. This is very important, because that class provides us a lot of template related functionalities.

Secondly, you can see that, I defined a custom method `getText()`. The usage of this method will be discussed later.

### Layout Update XML file

File : `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\rkt_customblock.xml`

```
<layout>
    <rkt_customblock_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="rkt_customblock/helloworld" name="myblock.helloworld" template="rkt_customblock/helloworld.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </rkt_customblock_index_index>
</layout>
```

`<rkt_customblock_index_index />` is known as layout handle. More specifically we can call this layout handle as `controller action layout handle`. This is because, the layout definition inside this layouthandle will get included in the layout only when a specific controller action is get executed. In the above case, this layout handle will get processed only when `indexAction()` method present in `IndexController.php` of `Rkt_CustomBlock`.

`root` block is used to set a page template for the page. We included our custom block inside `content` block. (`root` and `content` blocks are core blocks which are used in magento layout construction. These blocks has specific usages).

This is how our block is defined inside our module

```
 <block type="rkt_customblock/helloworld" name="myblock.helloworld" template="rkt_customblock/helloworld.phtml" />
```

`type` : this is used to recognize the block class. Here `rkt_customblock/helloworld` stands for the block `Rkt_CustomBlock_Block_Helloworld`.

`name` : name of the block. It should be unique.

`template` : this is the template file which is going to use by the block.

### Define Template

File : `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\rkt_customblock/helloworld.phtml`

```
<h1>Hello World !</h1>
<p>Hello... Can you see me ? If yes I just want to say</p>
<h4><?php echo $this->getText(); ?></h4>
```

Here you can see that, we are calling to the method `getText()` which is defined inside your custom block. This means that, `helloworld.phtml` file is actually an instance of `Rkt_CustomBlock_Block_Helloworld`.

Now, go and clear the cache and load the page `www.yourdomain.com/helloworld`. You will find an output like this.

> Hello World !
>
> Hello... Can you see me ? If yes I just want to say
>
> I am inside `Rkt_CustomBlock_Block_Helloworld` block and it is my
>   first custom block ever !

**Note 1**: This module is based on `Magento 1.9` and later. For all lower version, you can use `base/default` package theme for your layout instead of `rwd/default`.

You can quickly **[refer this small extension here](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/MagentoStackExchange_Helper/tree/Rkt_CustomBlock)**. Let me know if you have any doubts !!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. can you also extend it to access a database table if possible

Comment: @beginner: It is too broad.. There are lot of tutorials available online. You can follow that. If you have specific doubt, feel free to ask another question here. If I write a post about database integration in a custom extension, then I will let you know. Happy to help you. :-)

Comment: lets say i have a database name client and its primary key is scid. i want to display clients information in a page. it needs to be sorted by the scid.

Comment: heres an example, http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54, i want to get access to the table and put the database entry in a form. update edit load and delete.

Comment: @beginner : I got your point. Try those free available blogs right now. I am currently busy. Creating and explaining magneto model structure require a lot of time. If you find any problems while doing this, feel free to come here and post another question. But remember question should be specific.