# New block in custom module from controller not loading

Tags: controllers

I'm making a new page controller in my store, but the current configuration does not load the new block on the page. What is the probable error? And yes, I cleared the cache, and are disabled. The referent of my config.xml code is:

```
<Frontend>
        <Routers>
            <Helloworld>
                <Use>standard </use>
                <Args>
                    <Module>ITEP_Incomm </module>
                    <FrontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </Args>
            </Helloworld>
        </Routers>
</Frontend>

        <Blocks>
            <InComm>
                <Class>ITEP_Incomm_Block </class>
            </InComm>
       </Blocks>
```

Ok ... now the controller code (IndexController.php):

```
<?php

ITEP_Incomm_IndexController class extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    indexAction public function () {    $This->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock(root)->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
$ This-> renderLayout ();
    }
}
```

The block.php code:

```
<?php
ITEP_Incomm_Block class extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

And the call in my file the theme folder / layout / incommmenu.xml is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Layout>
    <ITEP_Incomm_index_index>
            <Block type="InComm/block" name="newreferenceBlock" template="test/example.phtml" />
    </ ITEP_Incomm_index_index>
</Layout>
```

When access localhost:8080/magento/helloworld / my theme carries the top menu and footer, but the content is empty, my block did not load. What's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see a lot of mistakes in those codes. Before showing you each and every one, I would like to show you how should those codes should appear.

File : `app\code\local\ITEP\Incomm\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ITEP_Incomm>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </ITEP_Incomm>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <itep_incomm>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ITEP_Incomm</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </itep_incomm>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <itep_incomm>
                     <file>incommmenu.xml</file>
                </itep_incomm>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <itep_incomm>
                <class>ITEP_Incomm_Block</class>
            </itep_incomm>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

File : `app\code\local\ITEP\Incomm\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class ITEP_Incomm_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

File : `app\code\local\ITEP\Incomm\Block\Hello.php`

```
<?php
class ITEP_Incomm_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

File : `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\incommmenu.xml`

```
<layout>
    <itep_incomm_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="itep_incomm/hello" name="helloworld.block" template="test/example.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </itep_incomm_index_index>
</layout>
```

File : `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\test\example.phtml`

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<p> Welcome to the Magic world of Magento. </p>
```

File : `app\etc\modules\ITEP_Incomm.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ITEP_Incomm>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ITEP_Incomm>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You are done. Now clear the cache and try to load the page `www.your-domain.com/helloworld` and most probably you can see the result.

### The Mistakes That You Have Done

- Basically almost all node that magento provides in default configurations are lower-cased nodes. Basically `<block />` node is not equal to `<Block />`. Both are different for magento.
- You are using camel-case letter in every page and in every file as the first letter. This is wrong. You should stick with basic rules. ie `I am`  not equal to `i am` for Magento.
- You are using unwanted spaces everywhere and it is again wrong.
- You are even declaring classes wrongly !
- I didn't understand what is this `<? Php` ?

### What You Need To Do

- You should study basics of PHP first
- Then you should study basics of Magento.
- Then you should study how extensions are developing in Magento.
- Then you should put your Magento instance in developer mode and then play with it.
- Next time, please avoid to ask such awkward questions here.

### EDIT

I have created this extension for your reference.I checked this in my Magento instance and it is working perfectly. ***[So use this as your reference](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/MagentoStackExchange_Helper/tree/ITEP_Incomm)***.

Comment: block not load yet, I plan to study yes (I already have a php book purchased =)) but I thoroughly analyzed the code, Upper and lower and referring to the block code appears to be correct. I wonder what the error to avoid future uncertainties ,Thanks
`  <itep_incomm>
                <class>ITEP_Incomm_Block</class>
      </itepincomm>`

`<fourward_incomm_index_index>
...
<block type="fourward_incomm/hello" name="helloworld.block" template="fourward/incomm/customer/incomm_menu.phtml" />
</...>`
The layout is being loaded (because 1column is in xml only), less the portion relating to the block

Comment: This code works perfectly. I checked it now. Please have a look on this thread first http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/how-to-create-a-custom-block-in-custom-module and checkout my answer over there. Also I have created  this module for reference. Have a look on the edit section of my answer