# How to alphabetically sort categories?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a page that is setup to display all product categories. How do I sort these alphabetically?

This is what the block looks like

{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/cat-thumbnails.phtml"}} {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/sidebar-fix.phtml"}}

I just want to alphabetize it.

Comment: How are you pulling the collection in your template .phtml files?

Comment: @Goku I am unsure I have been working on Magento for 2 days. Where would I look for this?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create on **block file** in your custom module,for example here I create one block file and in that file, you set custom category collection.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Getcategory extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function getCategory($page,$limit)
    {
        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('in' => array(1)))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('neq' => array(1)))
        ->addIsActiveFilter()
        ->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');


    return $categories;

}

}
```

now call phtml with this block name like,

```
{{block type="module/blockname" template="catalog/category/cat-thumbnails.phtml"}}
```

and get the custom collection in your phtml.

Comment: I am brand new to Magento. Do you know of a tutorial that takes a step back for this? How do I create a block file in the custom module?

Comment: Hi, Please refer this link for how to create custom module of Block then after simple call this block.

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/how-to-create-a-custom-block-in-custom-module